# Remove tooltip if title attr is empty

Tags: jquery

I am trying to modify this code so if the title attribute of my link is empty, then the #tooltip won't show up:

```
this.tooltip = function(){  
    /* CONFIG */        
        xOffset = -23;
        yOffset = -150;     
        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result     
    /* END CONFIG */        
    $("a.tooltip").hover(function(e){                                             
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";                                      
        $("body").append("<p id='tooltip'>"+ this.t +"</p>");
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;        
        $("#tooltip").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.tooltip").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#tooltip")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};



// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    tooltip();
});
```

you can view a live sample here: http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/01/

I am trying to implement this in my CMS. The title attr will be generated via a custom field. If the custom field content is not provided, an empty #tooltip pop-up still shows up but I want to get rid of it if the title attr is empty.

Comment: Just put `if ( this.title.length === 0 ) return;` at the top of your event handlers ?

Comment: If the title attribute is being generated through some programatic means, then you could determine whether or not to add the `tooltip` class to that element at that time.

Comment: @PatrickQ that'a a good point. But for some reason, this doesn't work: if ($('a.gec-link').attr('title')) { $('a.gec-link').addClass('tooltip'); }

Answer (score 0):

If there is no title attribute at all the attribute selector would filter out the elements of that class that only have `title` attribute

```
$("a.tooltip[title]").hover(....
```

Comment: This will only work if the title attribute is not present. It will not work if the attribute is present but empty.